# Background colour in Apple News story header

Tags: apple-news

How to change the background colour of the top header bar (where the transparent brand logo seats) of story/article pages, in Apple News ?

Couldn't find at configuration in iCloud News Publisher > Settings > Branding

Does the brand need to be registered at https://register.apple.com/business/ui ?

Tried following via article.json, but didn't work

```
 "documentStyle": {
        "backgroundColor": "#F8F8F8"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The color of that bar cannot be changed in code or in iCloud News Publisher. If you have a publisher representative at Apple, you can work with them to customize the color of that bar.